# How Can I Get SUM Array On Laravel5?

Tags: postgresql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, postgresql-9.5

My postgresql database like this.

```
SELECT * FROM point_records;

 id | user_id | point |     created_at      |     updated_at
----+---------+-------+---------------------+---------------------
  1 |       1 |   100 | 2017-01-27 09:39:47 | 2017-01-27 09:39:47
  3 |       2 |   100 |                     |
  4 |       2 |   100 |                     |
  5 |       3 |   100 |                     |
  6 |       3 |   100 |                     |
  7 |       3 |   100 |                     |

SELECT user_id, SUM(point) AS points FROM point_records GROUP BY(user_id) ORDER BY points desc;

 user_id | points
---------+--------
       3 |    300
       2 |    200
       1 |    100
```

I wanna get point ranking to array. So now I do this.

```
$points = \App\PointRecord::selectRaw('member_id, SUM(point) AS points') -> groupBy('member_id') -> orderBy('points', 'desc') -> get() -> toArray();

$your_score = array_search($user -> id, $points) + 1;
```

this $points array return this.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => 3 [points] => 150 ) [1] => Array ( [user_id] => 2 [points] => 100 ) [2] => Array ( [user_id] => 1 [points] => 10 ) )
```

But I don't wanna use Raw. I'm looking for other ideas.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your solution is already work why you want to change raw to another.
anyway if you really want to change you need to add more code try this

```
    $outputs = [];
    $query = \App\PointRecord:::groupBy('member_id')->get();
    foreach ($query as $e) {
        $data = $e->toArray();
        $data['point'] = $e->where('member_id', $data["member_id"])->sum('point');
        $outputs[] = $data;
    }
    dd($outputs);
```

Comment: hmm...sum(point) return integer, But groupBy can't call on that. But I dont' know addSelect thank you.

Comment: thanks reply. whoa, sounds complicated.I use raw. Why I wanna change raw, Cuz I'm afraid of stop working if change DB to mysql from postgres someday, And raw causes at the risk of sql injection. So I don't wanna use raw if I can